# Java SWT UI Thread freeze even if run in new Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, swt

I have a problem with a long running task.

After my dialog is shown I want to scan a ftp directory. This task takes some time so I need to run this task no in the UI thread.

My idea was

```
@Override
protected void postDialogOpen() {

    // if invoked via menu button
    if (!scanFtp) {

        final Display display = Display.getDefault();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                //initProgressWaitViewer();

                scanFtpServer();

                //closeProgressWaitViewer();

                display.syncExec(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        updateTree();
                    }

                });

            }

        }).run();

    }

}
```

But during the execution of scanFtpServer() my dialog is not movable and if I click on it it becomes "unresponsible".

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use `start()` to execute a thread. If that not solve all problems.. maybe some more code is required..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to do `.start()` instead of `.run()` .

Comment: Yes you are right! Dump question. Calling the run method starts it on the current (UI Thread) of course.

Comment: U can accept this answer or the answer of @rhobincu which is more detailed. So that people know this problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

When calling method `run()` in class `Thread`, you are executing the method on the caller thread, just like calling any other method. If you want to spawn a new thread and execute method `run()` in that thread, you need to call method `start()` instead, that will do all the work of setting up the thread and running it.

So replace

```
}).run();
```

with

```
}).start();
```